# websphere 7.0 JAXWS webservice deployed in tomcat 7.0 not working

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

Friends:

I have a JAXWS webservice developed in WebSphere 7.0. It is working there. The stack in Websphere is Axis2.0

I wrote a POJO Java class, annotated with the @WebService annotation and then I did a wsgen to generate the necessary artifacts and created the war file.

The imp thing is that web.xml does NOT have any servlets in it or listeners defined.
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"    
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>CMSExternalWebServices</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Log4JControl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.openutils.log4j.Log4jConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Log4JControl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Log4JControl/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

However when I deploy that war file to Tomcat 7.0 and then copy the axis2 jars to the WEB-INF\lib folder.

When I restart Tomcat, the WebService does not work.

What I am curious is, how come Websphere7, deploys the WebService on startup without any entires in web.xml but Tomcat refuses to do so ?

What am I missing ?

-Narahari

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere searches the classpath for `@WebService` annotations during startup, it is not necessary to have any entries in `web.xml`, this is according to Java EE 6 specification.

As Tomcat does not fully support Java EE 6 (it's a servlet engine 'only'), you must define a trigger to get Axis2 to load your web services. As far as I know you must define each Web Service in `web.xml` to be able to run on Tomcat (I may have missed some enhancements).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the deployment artifacts generation a feature of the container or is can it be augmented by other WS engine jars like axis2 or metro aka if I drop in those jars inside of \lib then the annotation classes are auto processes at deploy time ?

-Narahari

Comment: Artifact generation should work as long as they are compatible with JAX-WS API. Some time ago I generated atrifacts using WebSphere command line tools and deployed on Tomcat...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're trying to deploy it, but I think you're assuming Tomcat works like a full Java EE server, which it isn't.

If you take the axis jar and put it as its own web app, it *should* work (see [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/pojoguide.html#pojows).

I don't know that Tomcat would do anything at all with a @WebService annotation, since it *isn't* a full Java EE server. See [here](http://byprogrammerforprogrammer.com/2009/11/java-web-service-annotations-in-tomcat/), although that's with Tomcat 6, not Tomcat 7.

See also [this](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/web_service_tutorial) which leads me to believe it *might* support it, but it looks like it's still using Metro.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen a similar thing before (i.e. the web services not being listed in the `web.xml` file). Are there any other XML files in the `WEB-INF` or `META-INF` called `ibm-something-something.xml` or similar? From memory, that's where the info was when I was developing in Rational Application Developer and deploying to WAS 7.